# WinAPI from a script, not the ISE

Tags: winapi, powershell, types

I am using this code and it works fine in the ISE but not when run as a script. The error I get is "Specified cast is not valid" and it occurs at the last line shown here. I am thinking it is the Set-Type that is actually the problem, but I removed -ignoreWarnings and I get no indication of a problem. I get the same error if I launch the script with Run as administrator or not. My hope is that WinAPIs isn't something that is limited to the ISE

```
Add-Type -typeDefinition @'
using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
namespace WinAPIs { 
    public class UserAccountPicture { 
        [DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "#262", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)] 
        public static extern void SetUserTile(string username, int notneeded, string picturefilename); 
    }
}
'@ -ignoreWarnings
[WinAPIs.UserAccountPicture]::SetUserTile($userName, 0, $imagePath)
```

I also tried an alternate approach with the same results.

```
$methodDefinition = @'
[DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "#262", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern bool SetUserTile(string username, int notneeded, string picturefilename);
'@

$shell32 = Add-Type -memberDefinition:$methodDefinition -name:'shell32' -namespace:'Win32' -passThru

$shell32::SetUserTile("RTC", 0, "$scriptPath\RTC.bmp")
```

I am rather out of my element here, so hopefully someone can point me at my mistake. Or verify that I just can't do this in a script.

thanks!

Comment: How did you start the script? Right click and run, or interactive in a powershell console? Have you checked your executionpolicy? Do you know if the scripts runs at all? Does the script run if you use `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "c:\myscript.ps1"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this post](http://undoc.airesoft.co.uk/shell32.dll/SHSetUserPicturePath.php):

> `CoInitialize(NULL)`/`CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED)` must
>   be called prior to calling this function.

Have you tried to call this functions beforehand?

What's your PowerShell version? Because this may be related to [STA\MTA](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/02/09/weekend-scripter-playing-around-with-powershell-namespace-apartmentstate.aspx) modes:

> Did you know that in Windows PowerShell 3.0, we changed the Windows
>   PowerShell console from multi-threaded apartment (MTA) to
>   single-threaded apartment (STA)? If you did not notice the change, you
>   are probably not doing anything that requires MTA mode. If all of a
>   sudden, you have some Windows PowerShell 2.0 or even Windows
>   PowerShell 1.0 scripts that no longer work, now you know why.

You can check your PS host's mode this way: `$host.Runspace.ApartmentState`

Even if you're using PS 3 and higher, you could try to launch PowerShell.exe with `-Sta` or `-Mta` parameters and see, if this makes any difference.

Moreover, I've tried your code on PS 5.0 and it works both in ISE and PowerShell console.

**UPDATE:** This is [defintely STA\MTA issue](http://joco.name/2010/12/06/i-discovered-the-new-windows-user-tile-api/):

> The function is in shell32.dll. It doesn’t have a name but the ordinal
>   262. It takes a username (MACHINE\user or DOMAIN\user format), a zero (the usual reserved stuff, I guess), and a picture path (can be any
>   well known format or size) parameter, and returns an HRESULT. If you
>   pass a null username, then the result of GetUserNameEx with a
>   NameSamCompatible parameter will be used. **It uses COM inside, and
>   only works on STA threads (otherwise throws an `InvalidCastException (0×80004002, E_NOINTERFACE)`).**

The thing I don't understand, is that why your PowerShell console runs as `MTA`, it shouldn't do this.

Comment: -Sta for the win! Thanks so much. Not a chance I was going to pull that out of a hat on my own. ;)